# Erro 403 no projeto Android com WebService usando Wampserver

Tags: android, mysql, apache, webserver

Depois de implementar o WebService no meu projeto e usar o DeBug para checar se está tudo certo, ele me retornou o erro 403 igual está na imagem. Depois de procurar sobre, confirmei que a programação do app está correta, os scripts PHP também estão corretos, então o problema é do lado do Apache com relação as permissões. Eu uso o Wampserver, aí entra o problema, porque essa parte já não é do meu conhecimento, então não sei como resolver. Tentei procurar, a maioria dos casos parecidos diziam para eu alterar algumas coisas no documento httpd.conf que fica dentro do Apache, mas pelo menos até agora não adiantou. Por enquanto só programei o app para buscar dados que estão na internet, eu os guardei no phpMyAdmin

.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você consegue acessar o script através do navegador? Se também der erro 403 provavelmente é a permissão da pasta ou no arquivo PHP.

Comment: Qual deles, o que eu uso como URL no projeto, que tá escrito na imagem, APISincronizarSistema? Tem esse e um outro onde eu guardei as informações do localhost, pass. O primeiro retorna "sucess = false" quando eu tento.

Comment: Então entendi que o problema tá nas permissões de acesso do Apache, o problema é que eu não sei onde altero isso, não entendo quase nada do Wampserver

Answer (score 0):

Como o Ricardo falou tente acessar a URL pelo navegador, a mesma que você está tentando acessar pelo app, se retornar 403 é problema de acesso a pasta ou permissões do seu programa php.

Para liberar as permissões tente o seguinte:

- no httpd.conf

Procure essas linhas:

```
<Directory/>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Então substitua por:

```
<Directory/>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Ainda no httpd.conf procure por:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

e substitua por:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from All
```

Salve e feche o arquivo e reinicie os serviços (Obs: sempre que você alterar alguma coisa em arquivos de configuração você tem que reiniciar para carregar a nova configuração)

[image: Restart all services]